# Recursive searching for a path in an Arraylist of rooms

Tags: java, arraylist, path-finding

I'm trying find a path in a dungeon with rooms, the rooms are connected by doors.
There is always only one way to get from one room to another room.
Can someone help me to construct a path? I've looked in to path searching algorithms but they are to complex for this example becouse there is only one possible path and therefor there is no need to add weight to the rooms.

This is the Room object I'm using:

```
public Room(int id, Tile centerTile, ArrayList<Room> neighbours, ArrayList<Door> doors) 

  id = unique room id

  centerTile = center of the room.

  neighbours = list of neighbouring rooms

  doors = list of doors leading to the neighbouring rooms
```

The rooms are being stored in an Arraylist called explored rooms.

This is what i got so far but it isnt working.

```
package pathing;

import room.Room;
import room.RoomUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Path {

public static ArrayList<Room> findPath(Room start, Room target) {

    ArrayList<Room> frontier = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Node> visited = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Room> path = new ArrayList<>();

    frontier.add(RoomUtils.getRoomById(start.getId()));
    visited.add(new Node(RoomUtils.getRoomById(start.getId()), null));

    if (start.equals(target)) {
        path.add(RoomUtils.getRoomById(start.getId()));
    } else {
        Iterator frontierIterator = frontier.listIterator();
        while (frontierIterator.hasNext()) {
            Room front = (Room) frontierIterator.next();
            front = RoomUtils.getRoomById(front.getId());
            if (front.getNeighbours().size() > 0) {
                for (Room room : front.getNeighbours()) {
                    if (room.equals(target)) {
                        frontier.clear();
                        visited.add(new Node(RoomUtils.getRoomById(room.getId()), RoomUtils.getRoomById(front.getId())));
                        frontierIterator = frontier.listIterator();
                    } else {
                        frontier.remove(RoomUtils.getRoomById(front.getId()));
                        visited.add(new Node(RoomUtils.getRoomById(room.getId()), RoomUtils.getRoomById(front.getId())));
                        frontierIterator = frontier.listIterator();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Node startNode = visited.get(0);
        Node backtrackNode = getFrom(visited, target);

        if (backtrackNode != null && backtrackNode.getCurrent() != null) {
            path.add(backtrackNode.getCurrent());
        }

        while (backtrackNode != null && backtrackNode.getFrom() != null && !backtrackNode.equals(startNode)) {
            path.add(backtrackNode.getFrom());
            backtrackNode = getFrom(visited, backtrackNode.getFrom());
        }
    }
    return path;
}

private static Node getFrom(ArrayList<Node> nodes, Room from) {
    for (Node node : nodes) {
        if (node.getCurrent().equals(from)) {
            return node;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private static class Node {
    private final Room current;
    private final Room from;

    public Node(Room current, Room from) {
        this.current = current;
        this.from = from;
    }

    public Room getCurrent() {
        return current;
    }

    public Room getFrom() {
        return from;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: We will need your `Room` and `Door` classes code. Also the code for your attempt to solve this problem would be welcomed.

Comment: every possible way is a path. What is your criteria to know if you find the path you're searching for ?

Comment: @michalk  I updated the question with the code that i got so far.

Comment: @Conffusion I need a path from room A to room B  but every room between A and B can have rooms to side so it isnt always a straight path

Answer (score 0):

The title of your question contains 'recursive' so I looked for a recursive solution. 
For each room you can say: if one of my neighbour rooms leads to the target room then I'm also part of the path. When none of your neighbours leads to the target then you are also not part of the path.

To make it recursive I've created a new method which starts from a current room.
The overall path and list of visited rooms are defined as class variables so they are still available after all calls to `checkRoom`.

```
package pathing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import room.Room;

public class Path {

    // list of all visited rooms to detect loops
    List<Room> visited = new ArrayList<>();
    // path from start to the current room
    List<Room> path = new ArrayList<>();
    Room target;
    boolean pathFound=false;

    public void checkRoom(Room current) {
        if(pathFound) {
            return;
        }
        if(visited.contains(current))
        {
            // we've been here before, we have detected a loop
            return;
        }
        path.add(current);
        visited.add(current);
        if (current.equals(target)) {
            pathFound=true;
        } else {
            // there are always neighbours (at least the room we come from
            for (Room room : current.getNeighbours()) {
                checkRoom(room);
                if(pathFound) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            // all neighbours processed without success
            path.remove(current);
        }
    }

    public static List<Room> findPath(Room start, Room target) {
        Path p=new Path();
        p.target=target;
        p.checkRoom(start);
        return p.path;
    }

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        //      2 - 3 - 4
        //      |   |
        //      1 - 5
        //      |
        //      6 - 7 - 9
        //          |
        //          8
        Room room1=new Room(1,new ArrayList<Room>());
        Room room2=new Room(2,new ArrayList<Room>());
        Room room3=new Room(3,new ArrayList<Room>());
        Room room4=new Room(4,new ArrayList<Room>());
        Room room5=new Room(5,new ArrayList<Room>());
        Room room6=new Room(6,new ArrayList<Room>());
        Room room7=new Room(7,new ArrayList<Room>());
        Room room8=new Room(8,new ArrayList<Room>());
        Room room9=new Room(9,new ArrayList<Room>());
        room1.getNeighbours().add(room2);
        room1.getNeighbours().add(room5);
        room1.getNeighbours().add(room6);
        room2.getNeighbours().add(room1);
        room2.getNeighbours().add(room3);
        room3.getNeighbours().add(room2);
        room3.getNeighbours().add(room4);
        room4.getNeighbours().add(room3);
        room5.getNeighbours().add(room3);
        room5.getNeighbours().add(room1);
        room6.getNeighbours().add(room1);
        room6.getNeighbours().add(room7);
        room7.getNeighbours().add(room6);
        room7.getNeighbours().add(room9);
        room7.getNeighbours().add(room8);
        List<Room> path=Path.findPath(room1, room9);
        for(Room room:path)
            System.out.println("Room:"+room.getId());
        }
}
```

EDIT: small optimalisation: every room always has at least one neighbour namely the room we come from so no need to check if there are neighbours. One exception possible when the maze has only one room but in that case start and target are the same at that is already tested before.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I'm going to test it out right away when i get home.